# Creating a Scroll View that pulls all data from an xml file

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimage, nsxmlparser

I am trying to create a "simple" photo ID app. The final product would be a series of images in a scroll view that you can click on to get more information. The images and data pertaining to the images, are all stored on a website in an XML file.

I can create an app that loads the xml into a table view, with the xml item title as the cell label, then when you click on the cell, a detail view is shown with the remaining details about the item. I can load and parse the xml into the table view without much issue. I cannot, it seems, translate this process into a scroll view app. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.lonhosford.com/lonblog/2011/05/24/xcode-4-iphone-mountains-of-the-usa-tutorial-lesson-7-add-detail-view/), and a few others like it, to achieve that result.

I have looked at the apple supplied examples of UIScrollView and several dozen YouTube videos and blog tutorials on the subject of implementing a scroll view, however I have yet to find any documentation on having the data pulled from xml. The scroll view is also going to be paging so the number of pages in the scroll view need to dynamically load from the number of items contained in the xml (similar to how the tableview knows how many rows to created based on item count).

I have made a scroll view app that loads 3 pages at a time and loops, like in [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html). (Half way down there is a section labeled 3 Pages Only.) This app, along with the Page Control sample that Apple provides, defines the number of pages that are to be displayed, they don't pull from the plist or xml data how many items there are and adjust accordingly.

I don't know that my existing code will be of any use to anyone as it's almost identical to the related tutorials listed above. If someone wants to see something specific, let me know and I'll post it.

Can anyone help me figure out what steps I need to take to create this app? If I can get my xml data to appear in the scroll view (each item on its own page) and have the number of pages determined dynamically, I'd be pretty set and can adjust it to include images and worry about making it "clickable" later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled on this awesome tutorial! Don't hunt for his source code and use that as it doesn't work properly. I had to tweak it a little bit to work in iOS 5, but it works. Converting it to iPad was as simple as changing the measurements. If anyone has questions about how I made this work, let me know. [video posted here](http://ontwik.com/objective-c/using-nsxmlparser-to-pull-uiimages-off-the-web/)